# Segue left to right Swift

Tags: swift, animation, segue

I'm working on a project where I want to have a custom segue with a left to right animation instead of the standard Apple bottom to top animation.

I've managed to do so in a navigation based app earlier by using this code:

```
override func perform() {
    var src: UIViewController = self.sourceViewController as! UIViewController
    var dst: UIViewController = self.destinationViewController as! UIViewController
    var transition: CATransition = CATransition()
    var timeFunc : CAMediaTimingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    transition.duration = 0.25
    transition.timingFunction = timeFunc
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft
    src.navigationController!.view.layer.addAnimation(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    src.navigationController!.pushViewController(dst, animated: false)
}
```

However now I want to do this in a project containing no nav bar and I can't seem to figure out how to do this without the nav bar.